# Minimum number of native-code combos required for a cross-platform Java application

Tags: operating-system, jvm, cross-platform, native, 32bit-64bit

I have a Java application which uses some native code. This application needs to run on the largest set of machine-OS-JVM platform combos, but here are the main ones I'm targetting initially:

1. *Machine types:* 32-bit and 64-bit
2. *OSes:* Windows, Linux, and Mac
3. *JVMs:* 32-bit and 64-bit

**Question 1:** Which of the following combos are valid by themselves (without even bringing my application into the picture)? It'd be great to also know a one-line reason for the invalid combos other than simply knowing they are invalid.

```
====================================
    hw      os      jvm     valid?
====================================
1.  32      32      32      yes
2.  32      32      64      
3.  32      64      32
4.  32      64      64
5.  64      32      32
6.  64      32      64
7.  64      64      32
8.  64      64      64      yes
====================================
```

By 'valid', I expect that not only the application should run, it should also run flawlessly - without even intermittent crashes, hangups, slowness, etc

**Question 2:** I know I can use Java's System properties to determine the values of the above parameters (hw, os, and jvm) and then dynamically load the appropriate version of my native code. But I'd like to know the minimum number of combo versions I can ship my application with, given that my application does not need to use the extended memory nor any potential speed improvements offered by 64-bit platforms.

Comment: for question one as a general rule hw >= os >= jvm so 2,3,4,6 are invalid. However from the point of view of an application 1 and 5 are identical.

Comment: That was an amazing piece of info! Please consider posting it as a response, and I'll consider marking it as final if there are no other better responses. Thanks, +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the width of the hardware must be greater than or equal to the width of the os which must be greater than or equal to the width of the application. Also the application is generally oblivious to the maximum width of the hardware so there are only three configs that matter:

32 bit os - 32 bit app
64 bit os - 32 bit app
64 bit os - 64 bit app

Now if the app is 32 bit it normally doesn't matter if the os is 64 bit. (it can if you're working with drivers or things that work inside the os) So you need one 32 bit and one 64 bit version per platform. So six versions in total.